# Why isn`t random generator working? Python

Tags: python

I`m pretty new in python. When I run that python code it just doesn't show anything! Any opinion?

```
import random 

q = 1
w = 2
e = 3
r = 4
t = 5
y = 6
u = 7
i = 8
o = 9
p = 10

lista = (q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p)

numero = random.choice (lista)


if numero == (q,w,e,r,t):
    print ("The colour is: Black")

if numero == (y,u,i,o,p):
    print ("The colour is: Red")
```

Thank you,
Ricardo Rocha

Comment: Replace `==` with `in` in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing you random `int` with `tuple`:
Change to:

```
if numero in (q,w,e,r,t):
    print ("The colour is: Black")

if numero in (y,u,i,o,p):
    print ("The colour is: Red")
```

Answer (score 0):

result of `random.choice(lista)` is an integer. You should check that if that exist in your tuple or not:

```
if numero in (q,w,e,r,t):
    print ("The colour is: Black")

if numero in (y,u,i,o,p):
    print ("The colour is: Red")
```

Answer (score 0):

One option to get % is to slice the `lista` in two based on `percent` required:

```
import random 

lista = ('q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p')

letter = random.choice (lista)

percent = 0.20
slice_here = int(len(lista)*percent)

print(lista[:slice_here]) #=> ('q', 'w')
print(lista[slice_here:]) #=> ('e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p')

if letter in lista[:slice_here]:
    print ("The colour is: Red")

if letter in lista[slice_here:]:
    print ("The colour is: Black")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the numero is EQUAL to the tuple. You can just change the if conditional to check if the element EXISTS inside the tuple using the keyword `in`

```
import random 

q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
lista = [q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p]
numero = random.choice(lista)

if numero in (q,w,e,r,t):
    print ("The colour is: Black")

if numero in (y,u,i,o,p):
    print ("The colour is: Red")
```